# the output of subprocess is different from the ffprob outptu

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ffprobe

I am trying the find the bitrate of each video and for this I used the following python command:

```
subprocess.call(['ffprobe', '-i',pname1,'-v', 'quiet', '-show_entries', 'format=bit_rate', '-hide_banner', '-of', 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1'])
```

`pname1` is the name of the file. but the output is zero for all files while when I used the same code in the shell the output is true and shows the true value for bitrate.

```
ffprobe -i 1.mkv -v quiet -show_entries format=bit_rate -hide_banner -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1
```

do you know what is the problem?

Comment: I just ran this and it worked fine. is the output `0` or is there no output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the return value of `call()` method and that is 0 which is succesfull. To get bitrate value as output, you can use `subprocess.check_output()`

```
output=subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i',pname1,'-v', 'quiet', '-show_entries', 'format=bit_rate', '-hide_banner', '-of', 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1'])

print(output)
```